# Javascript scope chain hoisting

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope, hoisting

I am kind of confused how lexical scoping is being done in JavaScript, for example

```
function outer(){
    a = 5;
    function inner(){
        console.log(a);
        var a = 10;    //hoisting
    }
    inner();
}
outer();
```

If we redefine `a` in line 5, then it will print `undefined`.  Why is that? Why doesn't the interpreter traverse up and check `outer.VO` even though `a` can be found in `inner.VO`, but it is being used before it is defined?

Comment: vars go to the top, so your code is really function inner(){ var a; console.log(a); a=10; }

Comment: Because that's exactly what hoisting means: It will not traverse the scope chain further, because the identifier **is already found in the scope of `inner`**, and resolves to the inner `a` variable even if that has not yet been initialised.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can remember, hoisting causes that `inner` function to be interpreted as such:

```
function inner(){
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a = 10;
}
```

So when you assign `a` to 10, it looks up the scopes until it finds the definition for `a`, which is at the `var` statement inside the `inner` function. It sees no need to go outside of that so it acts like the `a` in the `outer` function doesn't exist. Also, when `var a;` is executed, `a` is set to `undefined` by default. That's why you're seeing `undefined` for output.

I will explain this a bit wider 
Javascript interpreter does the following when it encounter a function (This is known as Execution Context)
A- Creation Stage
1- first step it makes an inaccessible object called variable object, it looks like that for your outer function

```
a: undefined 
inner : pointer to function
```

2- It defines the scope chain of the function and  the value of 'this'

B- Code Execution Stage
It executes the code line by line

and if it encountered a call to a function that is not declared yet, it will execute it remember

```
    inner : pointer to function
```

If you called inner() before the declaration,it's okay but that doesn't work for anonymous functions

As it's treated like any variable

```
fn();
var fn = function () {..}
```

this won't work because its variable object will be like that

```
fn: undefined
```